# A little detail in a question about finding all zeros of $2z^5 +8z -1$ in the ring $\{ 1 < |z| < 2 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

The question is to find the number of zeros of the function  $f(z) = 2z^5 +8z -1$ in the ring $\{ 1 < |z| < 2 \}$. The answer to this question says that there are $4$.

So I used Roche's theorem in a standard way, and got to those results:

In $\{ |z|<1 \}$ there is one zero. In $\{ |z|<2 \}$ there are $5$ zeros.

So by subtracting the domains I get that there are $4$ zeros in $\{ 1 \le |z| < 2 \}$. What I don't understand is: why on the domain $\{ |z|=1 \}$ always $f(z) \neq 0 $.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note:  if $z$ is a zero, so is $\bar z$; if $|z|=1$ then $\bar z=1/z$

Comment: Triangle inequality gives $\lvert f(z)\rvert\geq -1+8-2=5$ on $\lvert z\rvert=1$.

Comment: As an aside: "annulus" would be a better word to use than "ring" here (I spent quite a few seconds working out what ring in the algebraic sense you were talking about before the penny dropped.)

Comment: Never heard that word before, but I will start using it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that when $|z|=1$, we have $|f(z)| = |2z^5+8z-1| = |8z - (1-2z^5)| \ge |8z| - |1-2z^5| \ge 8 - 3 = 5$.

Answer (score 2):

assume there is a solution $z_0$ on $|z|=1$ s.t f($z_0$)=0 than $2z_0^5 +8z_0-1=0$ therefore 
$2z_0^5=-8z_0+1$ so $|2z_0^5|=|8z_0-1|$ in contradiction for what you got by using the Rouche's theorem.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually a nice way to do it.